# Contribution Page-Amount page options now showing

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

0
down vote
favorite

Greeting, When I add new Contribution Page then chick on "Amount" option in CiviCRM, In the "Amount" options page all checkboxes and radio buttons except PayPal Standard checkbox will disappear also Minimum Amount and Maximum Amount text boxes not showing .

I open the page in 4 different web browser and I cleared the cash and flash my Drupal website and still these options now showing. I am using Drupal 7.41 and CiviCRM 4.6.10.

Please advice how to fix this problem.

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

Check it after deleting the civicrm temporary files (../files/civicrm/templates_c). If this will not fix your issue, then check your civicrm log file (../files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog). Here your will get more details about the error.